# My function in my Router doesn't Delete All my data AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have multiples id from (req.body => these are all the information that I want to delete)
Here is my function in my "Router" where normally I would delete all the data but it keeps deleting only 1 data.

```
// Delete questions
Router.route('/questions/delete')
    .post(Authorization.isModeratorAuthorized, function(req, res, next) {
        console.log("In router");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body)); //getting all the questions selected
        let questionId = [];
        for(let i = 0;i<req.body.length;i++){
            questionId.push(req.body[i]._id);
        }
        console.log(questionId);
        //{{$in:}}
            async.waterfall([
                function(callback){ Models.Question.findOne({ _id: questionId, moderatorId: req.user._id }).exec(callback); },//{{$in:}}
                function(question, callback){
                    console.log(questionId);
                    if(!question) return callback({ statusCode: 404, message: req.__("QuestionNotFound"), });
                    else Models.QuestionAnswer.remove({ questionId: questionId }, function(err){ callback(err, question); });//{{$in:}}
                    console.log("ici");
                },
                function(question, callback){ Models.Options.remove({ questionId:  questionId }, function(err){ callback(err, question); }); },//{{$in:}}
                function(question, callback){ question.remove(callback); console.log("ici remove"); },
            ], function(err){
                console.log("ici 3");
                console.log("2eme question id " +req.body);
                if(err) return res.status((err.statusCode != undefined) ? err.statusCode : 400).json({ status: false, error: err.message, });
                else return res.status(200).json({ status: true, error: null, message: req.__("DeletedSuccessfully"), });
            });
    });
```

If you have any solution or if you can explain I would appreciate it.

Comment: Guessing it might have to do with req.body.length. You probably need to parse it.

Comment: I do not think that is the issue because when I select 2 things to delete, my questionId got those 2. (even if I parse req.body.length ou req.body[i]._id)
```04/05 22:39:09.398  In router
04/05 22:39:09.398  "Data sent by the user that has to be deleted : [object Object],[object Object]"
04/05 22:39:09.399  5eb0977a354e1206684d7344,5eb09985cec1e506fc7c088e
04/05 22:39:09.407  5eb0977a354e1206684d7344,5eb09985cec1e506fc7c088e
04/05 22:39:09.408  ici
04/05 22:39:09.410  ici remove
04/05 22:39:09.417  ici 3
04/05 22:39:09.417  2eme question id [object Object],[object Object]
```

Comment: Are you parsing the body elsewhere?

Comment: no i do not parse the body at all

Comment: You need to. body-parser is a popular choice. Follow the instructions. It is very easy to get up and running. A few lines of code.
https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser

Comment: Just needed to do a basic select * with nosql syntax